# Can't write to filestream

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

I've created a fileStream and a streamwriter to write to this. Problem is my file is not showing up with any text. The objects have instantiated correctly and the path and everything is write, just can't see anything writing. Maybe a problem with the streamwriter?

```
public class Logger {
        StreamWriter sw;
        FileStream logFileStream;

        public enum LogLevel
        {
            Low,
            Medium,
            High
        };

        public Logger(string filePath)
        {
            //logStream = new StreamWriter(logFilePath, false);
            logFileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
            sw = new StreamWriter(logFileStream);
        }

        public void LogMessage(string message) {
            LogMessage(message, LogLevel.Low, false);
        }

        public void LogMessage(string message, LogLevel level, bool excludeFromLogFile){
            var prefix = string.Empty;
            ConsoleColor color = ConsoleColor.White;

            switch (level)
            {
                case LogLevel.Medium:
                    prefix = "?";
                    color = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    break;
                case LogLevel.High:
                    prefix = "!";
                    color = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    break;
            }
            if (!excludeFromLogFile)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", prefix, DateTime.Now, message);
            }
            Console.ForegroundColor = color;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", message);
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
```

I am instantiating this class and then calling `logger.LogMessage("poop", Logger.LogLevel.High, false);` and nothing is showing.

Thanks

Comment: Your logger class is keeping the `FileStream` and `StreamWriter` open. Data will typically not be flushed until you call `Dispose`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The writes are being buffered in memory, try calling `logFileStream.Flush();` at the end of each Log function.

You really shouldn't be keeping the file handle open between calls though, if I were you I would open and close it in each function. If you're doing a lot of logging then buffer it yourself in memory and dump the whole thing once it reaches a certain size.

Comment: What do you mean buffer it myself in memory? As in don't call flush until it reaches a certain size? how can i check the size of the buffer?

Comment: One option is to write it to a `MemoryStream` which you then write to with a StreamWriter. The `Position` property will tell you how much you've written so far and `GetBuffer()` will give you an array of bytes. Alternatively you can use `StringBuilder`, in which case `Length` will give you the length and ToString() will give you a single string. Personally I'd use MemoryStream in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct version of your example

- use autoflush = true in stream writer
- open/close stream in every request - if it is correctly implemented, autoflush is unnecessary (flush will be done after dispose StreamWriter)
- use FileMode.Append

```
    public class Logger
    {
        public enum LogLevel
        {
            Low,
            Medium,
            High
        };

        private readonly string _filePath;

        public Logger(string filePath)
        {
            //logStream = new StreamWriter(logFilePath, false);

            _filePath = filePath;
        }

        public void LogMessage(string message)
        {
            LogMessage(message, LogLevel.Low, false);
        }

        public void LogMessage(string message, LogLevel level, bool excludeFromLogFile)
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream) {AutoFlush = true})
                {
                    var prefix = string.Empty;
                    var color = ConsoleColor.White;

                    switch (level)
                    {
                        case LogLevel.Medium:
                            prefix = "?";
                            color = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                            break;
                        case LogLevel.High:
                            prefix = "!";
                            color = ConsoleColor.Red;
                            break;
                    }

                    if (!excludeFromLogFile)
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", prefix, DateTime.Now, message);
                    }

                    Console.ForegroundColor = color;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", message);
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```